# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\|z\|=1$ but $z \neq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I know I could use Dirichlet's test, but I am wondering if the Taylor series of $- \ln (1-z)$ can be used in some way to prove it for $\|z\|=1$, $z \neq 1$. I know the convergence radius is 1 so it is not straightforward.

I tried to change the center of the Taylor serie and used $y \in \mathbb{C}$ instead of zero and I obtained that if $f(z):= - \ln(1-z)$
\begin{align*}
f(z+y-zy) &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{n)}(y)}{n!}((z+y-zy)-y)^n = \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-y)^n}\frac{(z-zy)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}
\end{align*}
And for $\|z\|=1$, $z \neq 1$ the logarithm is finite but for $z = 1$ it is infinity but I think this is not a correct argument because I think that the Taylor serie is equal to the logarithm only if $(z+y-zy)$ is inside of a ball with $y$ as center and that ball is in an open domain where the logarithm is analytic, in this case this is that the ball doesn't intersect the points where the logarithm doesn't exists.

How could I use the Taylor serie of the logarithm to prove the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\|z\|=1$ but $z \neq 1$?

Comment: Do you know the Abel transform ?

Comment: If it is the one which says that if limit of $a_n$ goes to zero and the radius of convergence of the serie of $a_n z^n$ is 1 then it converges for $z \in \mathbb{C}, \|z\|=1, z \neq 1$ yes, I know it and it is like Dirichlet's test. But I want a solution using the serie of the logarithm if exists

Comment: I don't believe you can derive this convergence from the Taylor series of the logarithm alone. My suggestion is to use summation by parts: if $A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n z^k$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A(n) (\frac1n - \frac1{n+1})$. Using the geometric series formula, you can show this latter series converges absolutely.